# Why would the loss function not decrease when training a Keras NN using it's own classification?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to debug my NN. It converges whenever I use its own classification but when I use its classification and another one of its variables. It fails badly. I see no reason why it wouldn't converge at least based on it's classification.

Code:

```
//training variables
dummy_variable = ['Class', 'mBB']

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu', input_dim=len(dummy_variable)))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

data = df_k1_2[dummy_variable].as_matrix()

labels = df_k1_2['Class'].as_matrix()

// Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: The question is not clear to me, what do you mean by "use its own classification?" or "another one of its variables"? Also, df_k1_2 is not defined on the provided example.

Comment: I agree with Diedre, the question is not clear. You need to specify the input and outputs of the NN in the two cases, also describing the training dataset may be useful.